# Escape spaces in batch file that calls msysgit sh.exe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping, msysgit

I have a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) `run-sh.bat` that attempts to pass commands to `sh.exe` of [msysgit](/questions/tagged/msysgit):

```
rem My Batch File
cmd /c " "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "%1" "
```

The first parameter is passed in as the command. A simple working example:

```
run-sh.bat "' echo Hello '"
...
Hello
```

However, if the command has a path with spaces then the path gets chopped at the first space:

```
run-sh.bat "' echo "C:\Windows\Path\That Contains\Some Spaces\In\It" '"
...
C:\Windows\Path\That
```

Now, if I just paste the entire command directly in the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) (instead of using the parameter):

```
rem My Batch File
cmd /c " "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "%1" "
cmd /c " "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c ""' echo "C:\Windows\Path\That Contains\Some Spaces\In\It" '"" "
```

Then you can see that for that second echo the path comes out right:

```
run-sh.bat "' echo "C:\Windows\Path\That Contains\Some Spaces\In\It" '"
...
C:\Windows\Path\That
C:\Windows\Path\That Contains\Some Spaces\In\It
```

How can I get it to work as a parameter?

Should I modify the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)? Or change the way I am formatting the parameter at command line?

Comment: try to dequote the parameter and then quoted it again - `"%~1"`

Comment: @npocmaka I'm not sure what you mean? Can you elaborate?

Comment: `%~1` - means the first argument without quotes if there are any.set again quotes to be sure it will be passed to the next script correctly.If it has quotes already  with `"%1"` you will have additional pair of quotes which will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Tested solutions:

```
Using CMD:

  rem My Batch File
  CMD /c ""%programfiles(x86)%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c '%*'"

You don´t have to use CMD /C though. You can run it directly to avoid extra quotes:

  rem My Batch File
  "%programfiles(x86)%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c '%*'
```

Then when you call it, only use quotes on the path:

```
run-sh.bat echo "C:\Windows\Path\That Contains\Some Spaces\In\It"
```